# How to make regular expression with negative value or non negative value?

Tags: python

I am focusing on data with a regular expression. My data have this template:

```
Timestamp 1549033386  ID=02141592cc0000000700000000000000 Dest_ID=02141592cc00000007ffffffb0ba2c53 Nbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5 -91
```

I am using python and I implement this regular expression:

```
'Nbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5': r'\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*\sNbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5\s+([0-9]+)',
```

But It does not work correctly, the problem is with  the negative values that I have.

I have another example that works correctly:

```
Timestamp 1549033599  ID=02141592cc0000000600000000000000 Dest_ID=00000000000000000000000000000000Delay_T2R2 -1 

\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*Delay_T2R2\s+(-?[0-9]+)
```

Comment: Does changing the last group to `(-?[0-9]+)` work?

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: For clarity: the problem is only the last number possibly being negative and it works fine leaving the last number and its regex away? Does Engineeros fix work on its own? Can you check both, then put them together and check again? Please update the question with what exactly didn't work (of the proposed fix & without the number)

Comment: @user24343  the problem is the last number

Comment: @dina well, ``(-?[0-9]+)`` __does__ match possibly negative numbers. Does ``all(re.match('(-?[0-9]+)', s) for s in '1 188 -3 -733'.split())`` return ``True``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try this, it matches 3 groups:

```
1549033386
02141592cc0000000700000000000000
02141592cc00000007ffffffb0ba2c53
```

but the whole regular expression doesn't match because of the trailing `([0-9]+)` which, as you correctly note, doesn't match the negative number. Fixing the regular expression either this way:

```
\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*\sNbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5\s+([-0-9]+)
```

or this way, as suggested by Engineero:

```
\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*\sNbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5\s+(-?[0-9]+)
```

gives me a full match on all 4 capturing groups.

```
1549033386
02141592cc0000000700000000000000
02141592cc00000007ffffffb0ba2c53
-91
```

So I conclude that either fix does in fact work, and the failure to match that you report is caused by a confounding error.

To demonstrate that it must be a confounding error, try this at the interpreter prompt, to eliminate such errors:

```
>>> exp = r"\bTimestamp\s+([0-9]+)\s+ID=(\w{32})0*\s+Dest_ID=(\w{32})0*\sNbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5\s+(-?[0-9]+)"
>>> rx = re.compile(exp)
>>> m=rx.match("Timestamp 1549033386  ID=02141592cc0000000700000000000000 Dest_ID=02141592cc00000007ffffffb0ba2c53 Nbr_packet_not_acK_ti9-ti5 -91")
>>> m.groups()
('1549033386', '02141592cc0000000700000000000000', '02141592cc00000007ffffffb0ba2c53', '-91')
```

I tried this in Python 2.5, 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7. I don't have 3.5 anymore, but if there had been a bug of this seriousness in 3.5 I'm pretty sure I would have heard about it.

So it's not the version, and it's not the regular expression itself. That leaves the data, which might not look quite the way it looks in your question, or the code that surrounds the check.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  But it does not work really. I am using python 3.5